# Consolidate on categories in column and get counts for one column

Tags: python, pandas

This is a python pandas problem I'd like some assistance with.

I have a table that I'll simplify like this:

`+--------+-------+--------+-----------+
| Gender | State |  Age   | Purchased |
+--------+-------+--------+-----------+
| Male   | NV    | Adult  | Yes       |
| Female | NV    | Adult  | Yes       |
| Male   | FL    | Teen   | Yes       |
| Male   | FL    | Adult  | No        |
| Female | NV    | Teen   | No        |
| Female | NY    | Senior | Yes       |
| Male   | NY    | Senior | Yes       |
| Female | NY    | Adult  | Yes       |
| Female | NV    | Teen   | Yes       |
| Male   | NV    | Adult  | No        |
| Female | FL    | Senior | Yes       |
| Male   | Fl    | Teen   | No        |
| Male   | NY    | Teen   | Yes       |
| Female | NV    | Adult  | No        |
+--------+-------+--------+-----------+`

I want to consolidate for the category types on each column while counting the number of 'purchased', effectively producing something like this:

`+--------+----------+-----------+----+
|        |          |    Purchased   |
+--------+----------+-----------+----+
|        |          | Yes       | No |
| Gender | Male     | 4         | 3  |
|        | Female   | 5         | 2  |
| State  | State FL | 2         | 2  |
|        | State NV | 3         | 3  |
|        | State NY | 4         | 0  |
| Age    | Senior   | 3         | 0  |
|        | Adult    | 3         | 3  |
|        | Teen     | 3         | 2  |
+--------+----------+-----------+----+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of `crosstab` +`concat`

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df[x],df.Purchased)for x in df.columns[:-1]],keys=df.columns[:-1])
Out[273]: 
Purchased      No  Yes
Gender Female   2    5
       Male     3    4
State  FL       1    2
       Fl       1    0
       NV       3    3
       NY       0    4
Age    Adult    3    3
       Senior   0    3
       Teen     2    3
```

Comment: Wow awesome solution! Also why is the :-1 in the columns array needed?

Comment: @StacyGarfield that is for columns slice , since you want to do the count the value by each of the 'Gender', 'State', 'Age', and df.columns[:-1] just return those

Comment: @StacyGarfield also , if our solution work would you like upvote and accept ?

Answer (score 1):

my approach:

```
a = {}
for col in ['Gender', 'State', 'Age']:
    a[col] = (df.groupby(col).Purchased.value_counts().unstack())

pd.concat(a)
```

Comment: Good solution too Quang!